# How to search by laravel Eloquent Many to Many

Tags: laravel

three tables

#### user

```
id  name        
1   a    
2   b     
3   c
```

#### role

```
id  name        
1   aa       
2   bb      
3   cc      
4   dd
```

#### role_user

```
role_id  user_id          
1        1          
2        3          
2        1          
3        4           
3        3         
3        2         
3        1
```

Laravel Code:

```php
User::with('roles')->whereHas('roles', function($query) {
    $query->whereIn('role_id', [2, 4]);
})->get();
```

this query return user has role  2 or 4,
I want get user has role 2 and 4;
what can I do?

Comment: Show roles relation? it is belongsToMany??

Comment: `$query->where('role_id',2)->where('role_id',4)`

Answer (score -1):

To achieve what you're after you can use [havingRaw()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#raw-methods):

```
User::with('roles')->whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
    $query
        ->select('user_id')
        ->whereIn('role_id', [2, 4])
        ->groupBy('user_id')
        ->havingRaw('count(distinct(role_id))=2'); // 2 = The number of different roles i.e. count([2,4])
})->get();
```

When using `whereIn` you're essentially asking for retsults that include at least one of the values you pass to it. Using `having` in conjunction with `group by` allows you to stipulate that you want to include a certain number of them (in this case all of them).